# Which SMS Gateway / Service providers are available?

Tags: civievent, civimember, civireport, sms

We are an NGO that would like to use SMS to send out reminders for events and feedback tool. Which providers are supported by CiviCRM?

Comment: What country are you located in?

Comment: Agreed, country of most of your contacts can play a big role in your available choices.

Comment: The StackExchange format is very ill-suited to product and service recommendations, because the price and relative quality of offerings are ephemeral, and preference for one or another is often a matter of opinion.

Comment: IN general I would agree but this question was 'which are available' rather than 'which do you recommend', a bit like the wiki page that lists Payment Processors perhaps

Comment: Perhaps you'd be interested in the SMS Survey Extension? https://civicrm.org/blogs/johnff/sms-survey-release-candidate

Answer (score 3):

Out of the box, you have two possible providers, clickatell and twilio.

Both seems to work fine, you should check directly on their website because the cost depends on your location, the location of your recipients and the volume you want to send.

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Setting+up+a+SMS+Provider+for+CiviSMS

X+

Answer (score 2):

Besides Twilio and Clickatell, folks have written extensions for other gateways - but of course they may be out of date.
I know of these offhand:

MySMSMantra: https://github.com/osseed/com.osseed.sms.mysmsmantra/blob/master/README.md

PSWinCom: https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.pswincom