# Which SMS provider would you recommend?

Tags: sms

We want to implement a SMS gateway for a client and we are wondering about which one to choose.

I found and read [this post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10263/which-sms-gateway-service-providers-are-available) from 2016 and I'd like to know if there are new solutions or positive feedbacks with one of the four providers mentioned.

SMS would be sent / received in France.

Answer (score 2):

I guess its based on which provider you choose based on the budget or sms gateway fees. There few extension provided by Organization that integrates with SMS gateway

1. Clickatell
2. Twilio
3. Message Media
4. My sms myntra

You may also find more if you try to search for SMS gateway name with CiviCRM.

We have few clients using Twilio and have positive response so far, few others use different providers because of budget constraint and SMS charges, so we have implemented extension to support that(very simple to integrate).

Comment: do you know if I can use My SMS Mantra for France? The price per SMS is very low but I guess only in India.

Comment: Yes SMS mantra is only in India

Comment: But there are lots in sms providers in france and most of them provide api. Should be easy one to build(couple of hours)